# how to remove dynamic column

Tags: splunk, spl

I have two search using xyseries,so field name of these two search are dynamic and some of these field names are different.
now I want to combine these tow search ,and remove the different fields

I use |join -type outer to combine these two search table , but I don't know how to remove the different fields or keep same fields with search 1 in search 2

search 1:

fields aaaa aaa aaAa sjdk

---

count1    30    20    10    63

search 2:

fields aaaa aaa aaAa sjdk jdiw dwdd

---

count2    60    10    10    63    43    343

and now my table is like:
(using |join type outer)

fields aaaa aaa aaAa sjdk jdiw dwdd

---

count1    30    20    10    63
count2    60    10    10    63

Is there any method to remove empty column?
expect:

fields aaaa aaa aaAa sjdk

---

count1    30    20    10    63
count2    60    10    10    63

I'm trying use |foreach and |fields - , but it didn't work
because I can't get the field name correctly

Thanks

and I also want to know is there any way to change color by value with it's full dashboard , because fields name are dynamic and I don't want to manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some NULL fields after your `join`

If that is correct, the following *should* get you at least close:

```
<search that gets through the `join`>
| stats values(*) as * by <unique fields you know exist>
| fillnull value="-"
```

`stats values(...)` will *only* include fields for which there is *at least* one value in the previous events

`stats values(...)` *will* populate a NULL value for events that *did not have* the field in question - *iff* it existed with a value in *ay* event in the set

So follow it up with `fillnull` so you know where the fields existed (vs did not exist)